# Elasticsearch: make facets by category for complex query

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack, faceted-search

I am new to Elasticsearch and try to learn it from docs.
Now using Django-haystack 2.5.0 https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io and Elasticsearch 1.7.3

I need to implement dynamic facets: user have a form where he put names of facets, and after search is performed he is able to filter by these categories with sidebar filter form.

What i read in docs is facets implemented on fields, for example dates or authors, then filtering is done like this:

```
Tom (345)
Mary (218)
...
```

But this is not what i want. I have in my models only 1 text field and facets are aggregated dynamically during search.
So, for movie texts i want facets like this:

```
Detective (633)
Comedy (237)
...
```

and each genre is calculated by search query:

Detective

text: *"Columbo is an American television series starring Peter Falk as Columbo, a homicide detective with the Los Angeles Police Department.[2][3] The character and show, created by William Link and Richard Levinson, popularized the inverted detective story format, which begins by showing the commission of the crime and its perpetrator; the series therefore has no "whodunit" element. The plot revolves around how a perpetrator whose identity is already known to the audience will finally be caught and exposed (which the show's writers called a "howcatchem," rather than a "whodunit")."*

to detect category we search: `(cop | murder | crime | ...) and (story | ...)`

And the same search string for other categories.
I understand that explanations are unclear, but really not sure on what part of docs describe this.

Comment: Maybe show a few sample documents you have and what kind of facets you'd like to get out of them.

Comment: @Val edit done with example